# How do I write a command that allows me to copy from local machine to a node via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line

This is the command I used to copy some files from a source to target which was basically from a node to my local computer via powershell that I need to run it but I am wondering now how do I copy from my local computer to another node I want to target? So basically i am created 2 nodes and the first was from that source to my local computer where I stored the files so I want to create it back up to a 2nd node via my local computer. So i just need the right command to go from my local cpu to a new node. Any help please?

```
scp -i c:\Users\DarraghMartin\Horizon\goerli_key.pem -o 'StrictHostkeyChecking=no' -r goerliuser@10.41.5.102:/data/keystore/* c:\Users\DarraghMartin\Data
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're having? Why not just reverse the command like `scp -r c:\local\path user@node2:/remote/path`?

Comment: I am not able to correct the command line in the way it works for me. I seem to be overthinking it? I am aware it needs to be reversed but after user@node2: what would the rest of the line be?

Comment: The command syndax is just `scp [options] source target`. If I assume node1 and node2 are identical, then the whole command to copy the local `/Data` folder recursively to node2 could look like: `scp -i c:\Users\DarraghMartin\Horizon\goerli_key.pem -o 'StrictHostkeyChecking=no' -r c:\Users\DarraghMartin\Data goerliuser@Node2IP:/data/keystore/ `

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks so much. I was overcomplicating it

Answer (score 0):

The command syndax is just `scp [options] source target`. If I assume node1 and node2 are identical, then the whole command to copy the local `/Data` folder recursively to node2 could look like:

```
scp -i c:\Users\DarraghMartin\Horizon\goerli_key.pem -o 'StrictHostkeyChecking=no' -r c:\Users\DarraghMartin\Data goerliuser@Node2IP:/data/keystore/
```